# Graph a cubic in x-intercept form in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know that you can create graphs using polynomials, and creating data frames out of them, such as:

```
dat <- data.frame(x, y = x^3+x^2+x+5)
```

However, I wanted to know if it was possible to create a data frame to graph using the x-intercept form you get from factorised polynomials, such as:

```
(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)
```

Every time I try to define a variable with:

```
dat <- data.frame(x, y = (x+1)(x-1)(x-2))
```

I always receive the same error from it:

```
Error in data.frame(x, y = ((x - 1)(x + 1))(x - 2)) : 
    attempt to apply non-function
```

Is it possible to create a plot using only the x-intercept form, or do I need to expand first to be able to graph it in R?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the multiplication sign, like:

```
dat <- data.frame(x, y = (x+1)*(x-1)*(x-2))
```